# How to Set Paging in DataList control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Actually Datalist not contain allowpaging property. so how can i set paging in datalist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `PagedDataSource` class which encapsulates the paging-related properties of a data-bound control that allow it to perform paging.......

```
//creating the PagedDataSource instance....
pg = new PagedDataSource();
pg.DataSource = myTable;
pg.AllowPaging = true;
pg.PageSize = 10;

//Binding pg to datalist
dl.DataSource = pg;//dl is datalist
dl.DataBind();
```

Comment: i try it but it gives error                                                 PagedDataSource pg = new PagedDataSource();
            pg.DataSource = objclsfileupload.selectPendingContent(Session["UserId"].ToString());
            pg.AllowPaging = true;
            pg.PageSize = 1;
            DataList1.DataSource = pg;
            DataList1.DataBind();                               error:Cannot compute Count for a data source that does not implement ICollection.

Comment: error:Cannot compute Count for a data source that does not implement ICollection

Comment: You need to specify current page, next page and previous page in form which later programmed in code behind clas..Take a referece from this link: http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/DataList_Dynamic_Paging_PagedDataSource.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [Adding Paging Support to the Repeater or DataList with the PagedDataSource Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx#postadlink)

Create page level object of page datasource.

```
 PagedDataSource objPds;

// Populate the repeater control with the DataSet at page init or pageload
objPds = new PagedDataSource();
objPds.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

// Indicate that the data should be paged
objPds.AllowPaging = true;

// Set the number of items you wish to display per page
objPds.PageSize = 3;
```

Along this save the current page index in the viewstate or session.

```
public int CurrentPage
{
   get
   {
      // look for current page in ViewState
      object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
      if (o == null)
         return 0; // default page index of 0
      else
         return (int) o;
   }

   set
   {
      this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
   }
}
```

To move between page increment or decrement the page number as you like with your customizations:

```
private void cmdPrev_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Set viewstate variable to the previous page
   CurrentPage -= 1;

   // Reload control
   ItemsGet();
}

private void cmdNext_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Set viewstate variable to the next page
   CurrentPage += 1;

   // Reload control
   ItemsGet();
}
```

check this one also:
[Efficient Data Paging with the ASP.NET 2.0 DataList Control and ObjectDataSource](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/07/434787.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

i got answer ..

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            var data = objclsfileupload.selectPendingContent(Session["UserId"].ToString());// Iqueryable data
            var data2 = data.GetEnumerator();
            dt.Columns.Add("agegroup");
            dt.Columns.Add("contenttype");


            while (data2.MoveNext())
            {
                var record = (filuploadclass)data2.Current;
                dt.Rows.Add(record.agegroup, record.ContenetType);

            }

            pg.DataSource =dt.DefaultView ;

            pg.AllowPaging = true;
            pg.PageSize = 1;
            DataList1.DataSource = pg;
            DataList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: nice answer..  you really deserve down vote for this.. change your query for the error `error:Cannot compute Count for a data source that does not implement ICollection.` that you have answer. it is not regarding the set paging.  Use `data.ToList()` rather than single item fetch manually.