# DataList and SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello all fellow programmers.

I wanna make a paging of a database each consisting of 5 items and using a query opening the page. When i click the button i wanna change the query of the database connection and refresh the datalist with the new data consisting to that query(new 5 items) that i made but somehow my code needs a bit of help. I am a basic c# programmer and every help welcomed.

ASP

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Images/book-style.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Images/form.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Images/style.css" /> 
<span id="bookshead" />
    <div style="margin-top:50px" >
        <asp:DataList   ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID_AUTHOR"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" SeparatorStyle-Wrap="False">

            <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="books" style="width:530px;height:150px;margin-bottom:20px;border:1px dotted black;border-radius:5px;box-shadow:2px 2px 6px black;">
                <p class="book" runat="server"><%# Eval("TITLE") %></p>

                <p class="author"><%# Eval("NAME") %> <%# Eval("SURNAME") %></p>
                <img class="book-image" runat="server" alt="book image" src='<%# Eval("imazhi") %>' style="width:85px;height:130px" />
                <br />

                     <div class="addtowishlist" >
                        <a href="#" >Add to Wishlist</a>

                    </div>
                   </div>
            </ItemTemplate>


        </asp:DataList>
 </div>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="labe" Text="HELLLOO"></asp:Label>
<form id="ff" runat="server" >
<div id="Navigation" class="navigation">

    <div id="leftnav">
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="PreviousPageNav" runat="server" href="#bookshead" OnClick="updateBackward" Text="&lt;&lt; Librat e mëparshëm" />
        <asp:Label ID="PagerLocation" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button ID="NextPageNav" runat="server" href="#bookshead" OnClick="updateFoward" Text="&nbsp; Librat e ardhshëm&gt;&gt;"/>
    </div>



</div>
    </form>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eLibraryPConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="Select *FROM (AUTHORS a JOIN BOOKS_AUTHORS ba ON a.ID_AUTHOR=ba.ID_AUTHOR) JOIN BOOKS b ON ba.ID_BOOK=b.ID_BOOK WHERE a.ID_AUTHOR>=1 AND a.ID_AUTHOR<=5"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

AND The C#

```
private int firstItem=1;
private int lastItem=5;
public void updateFoward(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    firstItem += 5;
    lastItem += 5;
    SqlDataSource sql = new SqlDataSource();
    sql.ID = "SqlDataSource1";

    sql.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM (AUTHORS a JOIN BOOKS_AUTHORS ba ON a.ID_AUTHOR=ba.ID_AUTHOR) JOIN BOOKS b ON ba.ID_BOOK=b.ID_BOOK WHERE a.ID_AUTHOR>=" + firstItem + "AND a.ID_AUTHOR<=" + lastItem;
    labe.Text =sql.ID;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
public void updateBackward(object o,EventArgs e)
{
    firstItem -= 5;
    lastItem -= 5;
    SqlDataSource sql = new SqlDataSource();
    labe.Text = "Backward";
    sql.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
    sql.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM (AUTHORS a JOIN BOOKS_AUTHORS ba ON a.ID_AUTHOR=ba.ID_AUTHOR) JOIN BOOKS b ON ba.ID_BOOK=b.ID_BOOK WHERE a.ID_AUTHOR>=" + firstItem + "AND a.ID_AUTHOR<=" + lastItem;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

}

Comment: What is working and what isn't?

Comment: Already asked before. Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836830/how-to-set-paging-in-datalist-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: Gah! The sql injection flaw, it burns us.

Comment: @mGouda There a number of good reasons to avoid using the built-in paging features.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, could you please share some references, as I used to use built-in paging.

Comment: The built-in paging is okay: don't feel bad for using. It's just not always as efficient as it could be, and if someone wants to implement paging by hand that's a perfectly fine thing to do as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue to address here is that the `firstitem` and `lastitem` variables are defined at the class level in your page. It's important to remember that **every** event in ASP.Net results in a completely new instance of the class, and runs the entire page lifecycle: not just the event code itself. Anything from a prior instance of the page class is gone. Therefore, you click the "updateForward" button, for example, and the existing code will *always* give results running from 6 to 10, regardless of how many times you click it.

The quick solution here is to store this data either in the Session or in ViewState, instead of in the class. I'll use the Session as an example going forward.

The second problem is code that looks like this:

```
sql.SelectCommand = "Select * FROM (AUTHORS a JOIN BOOKS_AUTHORS ba ON a.ID_AUTHOR=ba.ID_AUTHOR) JOIN BOOKS b ON ba.ID_BOOK=b.ID_BOOK WHERE a.ID_AUTHOR>=" + firstItem + "AND a.ID_AUTHOR<=" + lastItem;
```

There are actually two problems here. The first is easy enough to correct: there isn't any spacing before the word "AND" after your `firstItem` substitution. The second problem will take considerably more work: the "string concatenation to include parameters" technique leaves you open to sql injection, and should be avoided. The good news is that the solution for this *major* security issue will also have the nice side effect of making your datasource work again.

To get started, let's first look at some of the existing ASP markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eLibraryPConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="Select * FROM (AUTHORS a JOIN BOOKS_AUTHORS ba ON a.ID_AUTHOR=ba.ID_AUTHOR) JOIN BOOKS b ON ba.ID_BOOK=b.ID_BOOK WHERE a.ID_AUTHOR>=1 AND a.ID_AUTHOR<=5">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

We want to change the markup to look like this:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:eLibraryPConnectionString %>"
     SelectCommand="Select * FROM (AUTHORS a JOIN BOOKS_AUTHORS ba ON a.ID_AUTHOR=ba.ID_AUTHOR) JOIN BOOKS b ON ba.ID_BOOK=b.ID_BOOK WHERE a.ID_AUTHOR>= @firstItem AND a.ID_AUTHOR<= @lastItem">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter name="firstItem" sessionfield="firstItem" type="Int32" />
        <asp:SessionParameter name="lastItem" sessionfield="lastItem" type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

If you wanted to use ViewState instead of the session, you could use an asp:ViewStateParameter instead. There are also asp:QueryStringParameters and some other options you can use.

The new markup tells the datasource about placeholders in the sql string, and also tells it where to find the data for those placeholders. The datasource will handle filling that data into the string itself... or rather, it won't. The great thing about query parameters done this way is that the parameter data is **never** substituted directly into the sql command, even on the database server, eliminating any possibility of sql injection attacks.

Now you can simplify your updateForward()/Backward() methods like this:

```
public void updateFoward(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["firstItem"] = (int)Session["firstItem"] + 5;
    Session["lastItem"] = (int)Session["lastItem"] + 5;
    DataList1.DataBind();
}
```

The udpateBackward() method will need a similar change. The switch to the long-form `x = x + 5` instead of `x += 5` is so that you can cast the `Object` Session value to an `int` at the proper point.

You'll also need code to seed the Session variables:

```
public void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         Session["firstItem"] = 1;
         Session["lastItem"] = 5;
    }
}
```